# Fixing IE6/7 problems when using floated elements inside of a button element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button

I am creating CSS buttons for both links and form submissions. I use almost the same markup for both, with a different wrapper.

HTML Examples:

```
<button type="submit">
  <em>Submit</em>
  <em class="cap"></em>
</button>

<a class="button">
  <em>Submit</em>
  <em class="cap"></em>
</a>
```

The CSS:

```
.button, button {
  display: block;
}
button em,
.button em {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: url(button.png) 0 0;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
button em.cap,
.button em.cap {
  padding: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background-position: 100% 0;
}
```

Now, in IE6/7, the anchor element version of this works. The problem comes in when using the button element, it causes the second em element to wrap.

I've tried some workarounds that I've found for button elements, but nothing I've found had a case quite like this. The reason I've floated the two elements left is because I need the button to be transparent, so other methods don't work here.

Here's an example of what I'm doing: http://keeleux.com/dev/button/

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a *big stack* of issues to consider here.

I'm going to be very verbose with the changes required to fix this.

To cajole it into working in IE6/7, these were my steps:

- Switch to using `display: inline-block` *instead* of `float` for the internals of the `button`.
  **See:** http://jsbin.com/omici3/2
- To fix the wonky alignment, we need to also add `vertical-align: top`.
  **See:** http://jsbin.com/omici3/3
- If you look at that previous demo in IE7, and click and hold the button, you can see it's too wide. We can fix that with `overflow: visible` (as per here: [IE7 CSS padding issue - cannot figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008500/ie7-css-padding-issue-cannot-figure-out/5008585#5008585)), and `display: inline`.
  **See:** http://jsbin.com/omici3/4

There's also some IE6 specific issues of low priority:

- The `button:hover` selector will not work in IE6. IE6 only supports `:hover` on `a` elements. To work around this, you can use the [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) fix.
- Due to your use of a `.png` image, in IE6 there is a grey background instead of transparency; there are fixes available. Though in this case, it's hard to notice. I'd say leave this one be - the extra effort is not worth the improvement.

More important is the fact that your current implementation is slightly broken in Firefox:

http://keeleux.com/dev/button/

[image] *(screenshot from Firefox 4)*

- See here for why: [Revisiting the Firefox button line-height bug... any 2011 solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863828/revisiting-the-firefox-button-line-height-bug-any-2011-solutions)
- The easiest way to workaround it in your case it to simply move the `line-height` to the internal `em`s.
  **The final fixed version:** http://jsbin.com/omici3/5

Note that a fair few of those issues can be worked around by simply using an `a` instead of a `button`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! The low priority IE6 issues you mentioned I wasn't really concerned about, I am aware of other workarounds if need be. Really it was just the button wrapping problem which you have fixed beautifully! Also thanks for the Firefox note, I was not aware of that.

Comment: By the way, the reason I was reluctant to use an anchor element instead of a button was that the button type="submit" will cause form behaviour to remain the same. If I remove the submit button in favour of an anchor tag that submits when clicked you lose the "enter to submit" on some browsers which then requires some more javascript workarounds. So thanks again! This was a large problem in a new site I'm working on.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Graceful degradation can be an important consideration.

Answer (score 1):

@Eric, save yourself time and go with a solution that's already been fought with and tested and verified in all the major browsers.....jQuery UI buttons does this right out of the box.  As an extra bonus, they can be styled with Themeroller for quick changeout on the backend and even user-selectable themes on the front-end.

Check out [this tut](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/) for more details.

Comment: Too many people seem to overlook the templating capabilities of jqui. +1

Comment: The reason I've not gone with this solution is due to the nature of my button. Your example relies on border-radius to have round corners, and would not be able to have a shadow unless done with CSS3. Both of these are unacceptable, since the whole issue here is that my buttons don't work in IE6/7. In case it's unclear what I am doing you can see an example here: http://keeleux.com/dev/button/. Also, your example is broken in IE7 (I didn't even bother checking 6). Screenshot here: http://keeleux.com/dev/button/example.png