# IE7 bug - can't make button float right

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a page that contains a button and a footer. I can't make the button float right. I have the following code:

```
<div style="float: right;">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" Text="Save"
        CssClass="button defaultbutton" />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I did some research on the net and found it is a known bug: [Fixing IE6/7 problems when using floated elements inside of a button element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885105/fixing-ie6-7-problems-when-using-floated-elements-inside-of-a-button-element)

But adding the CSS from the link didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Here is the CSS for button:**

```
display: inline;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
padding: 6px 24px;
border-radius: 2px;
```

**And here is the CSS for defaultbutton:**

```
background: #f24537;
border: 1px solid #d02718;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #810e05;
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with ASP so pardon my asking but what is <asp:Button /> spitting out to the client. I don't have an ASP-runnable server at hand but I can help you with the resulting HTML

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is rendered as html in the browser. What do you think is causing this display problem?

Comment: Can you show the CSS for button and defaultButton please? If you are using the ones from the link, then note that those styles are only being applied when <em.> is wrapped around the content. asp:button is rendered as input type="submit" on the client.

Comment: Could you try 2 things that may help: 1) Add a <div style="width:100%"> surrounded the floating element. or 2) Add that block just by itself on the page (not wrapped under any parent).

Comment: @aspdotnetuser I meant can you add what ASP processes <asp:button/> as; so what does the client receive? Right now I'm guessing its spitting out `<form action=""><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Save"/></form>` I'm using [http://www.csharpkey.com/aspnet/controls/button.htm](http://www.csharpkey.com/aspnet/controls/button.htm) as a reference by the way.

Comment: @Hawkin - the link takes you to a blank page

Comment: @dash, I have added the CSS to the question

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/keyTQ/2/ - does that work for you?

Comment: @dash, I tried that but it didn't make the button float right

Comment: I'm not near the IE7 machine right now, but how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/keyTQ/4/ - make the div stretch across the screen then align the contents to the right? Will take a look when I get back to it if no one else has answered ;-)

Comment: @dash, thanks for the suggestions but it didn't fix it

Comment: Inspect it in firebug and check to see if it is picking up some CSS from some where else. Maybe a pseudo class or something.

Comment: Also you may want to add `-moz-border-radius: 2px;` and `-webkit-border-radius: 2px;` `-o-border-radius: 2px;` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested what I think is the resulting code produced by ASP.

The exact page I'm testing is [here: http://jsbin.com/ololot](http://jsbin.com/ololot).

I've tried it out in IE7 [here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuXIf.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuXIf.png)

In Firefox on the same machine [here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh0i3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh0i3.png)

Unless the problem is the difference in padding, I don't seem to be able to replicate your problem.

*I'll edit the answer upon further information.*